# Error with basic React Example: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-rails

I'm trying to get react connected into my app. Its a rails app using rails-react (though I don't think that's part of the problem). I'm currently using a very simple 1 component setup:

```
// react_admin.js.jsx

/** @jsx React.DOM */
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
     <div className="commentBox">
       Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
   );
  }
});

React.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

My html file contains:

```
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="/assets/react.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/react_admin.js?body=1"></script>
</body>
```

I can see that rails-react is converting my react_admin.js.jsx into react_admin.js as follows:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var CommentBox = React.createClass({displayName: 'CommentBox',
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.DOM.div({className: "commentBox"}, 
        "Hello, world! I am a CommentBox."
      )
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  CommentBox(null),
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

However chrome is raising an ''Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'' in the Render.react() call, which it shows between "(" and "CommentBox(null)"

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you have the latest react version which should be v0.12.0. If you have any older versions, you should be using the now depreciated `React.renderComponent` as @jsanchez suggested below in the answers

Answer (score 67):

After 0.14 React moved to `ReactDOM.render()`, so if you update React, your code should be:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

But make sure to include both `react.js` and `react-dom.js` in your project since those are now separated.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me.  I am using v0.15

Comment: I am using like this but getting error. can you please healp me ReactDOM.render(<showData/>, document.getElementById('Ishim'));

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad it's hard to help based on your comment. Maybe you did not import ReactDOM in project? It is not enough to import React. `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: Thanks for reverting message, Now it's working, actually, I am watching old video of the react js

Answer (score 15):

You should update to the latest React library.

Some tutorials were updated to use `React.render()` instead of the deprecated `React.renderComponent()`, but the authors are still providing links to older versions or React, which do not have the newest `render()` method.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not very familiar with React, but it looks like you should be using `React.renderComponent` instead of `React.render`

By running your code generated by `rails-react` locally on my browser and playing with the `React` object, it looks like the `render` method does not exist. Instead, `React` contains a `renderComponent` method:

[image]

If you change the code to use `React.renderComponent` instead of `React.render`, the component gets rendered on the DOM.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/popksfb0/

Comment: renderComponent was just depreciated in the latest version, should be using React.render http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html#deprecations

Answer (score 2):

After 0.13.x React moved `React.renderComponent()` to `React.render()`.

Answer (score 2):

For reasons unknown to me I had to wrap mine in `{}`

So from:

```
import React from "react";
import render from "react-dom";
import Router from "./Router";

render(Router, document.getElementById ('app'));
```

To (**Working**):

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import Router from "./Router";

render(Router, document.getElementById ('app'));
```

Comment: That is because you are importing just `render` from ReactDOM. If you `import ReactDOM from "react-dom";` than you would have to use `ReactDOM.render(Router, document.getElementById ('app'));` Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import for more info.

Comment: For those who are new to ES6, remember to use exactly the variable {render}. Because you export only the "render" item of the complete module. If you want to use a different name you can use  -> `import {render as customRenderer} from 'react-dom';`

Answer (score 1):

For beginners, the error (type/undefined is undefined) may also show up due to the placement of React.render code block.

It should be placed after creating the components, preferably at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

React.render was introduced in version 0.12 as documented here: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html

To fix your issue upgrade to that version or higher. At time of writing the latest version is 0.13.3.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest React Starter Kit -> https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html
2. Use *react.js* and *react-dom.js* files on the build folder.
3. Instead of using the "text/jsx" use "text/babel" instead, referencing this minified library -> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js

Here's the full script referencing your initial code.

```
<style>
    .commentBox{
        color:red;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:bold
    }
</style>

<script src="build/react.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
    var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return (
              React.DOM.div({className: "commentBox"}, 
                "Hello, world! I am a CommentBox."
              )
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <CommentBox/>,
        document.getElementById('content')
    );
</script>
```